# ocamlfindがcompiler-libsを認識して名前が被るモジュールがコンパイルできない

Tags: ocaml

`ocaml 4.02.3`において、以下のコマンドで`longident.ml`というファイルを
コンパイルする際に下で示すエラーが表示されました。

`longident.ml`の中身は`type t = int`のみで、他にファイルがないディレクトリでコンパイルしました。
`longident.ml`はコンパイラのコードで`parsing/longident.ml`が存在するため
`ocamlcommon.cmxa`に含まれているからエラーになっていると思うのですが
なぜ`compiler-libs`が以下のコンパイルコマンドで`ocamlfind`により認識されているのでしょうか？

ちなみに`-package`から`batteries`、`sexplib`のどちらかを外した時にも同様のエラーが発生しました。
`-package`を書かないで`ocamlfind opt`でコンパイルした時には通常通りコンパイルできました。
`.opam/package/`から`batteries`と`sexplib`の依存関係とその依存パッケージの依存関係を見ても`compiler-libs`にdependしているという記述は見つけられませんでした。

```
ocamlfind opt -package batteries,sexplib.syntax -linkpkg -syntax camlp4o ./longident.ml 
findlib: [WARNING] Interface longident.cmi occurs in several directories: ., /home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs
findlib: [WARNING] Interface topdirs.cmi occurs in several directories: /home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs, /home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml
File "./longident.ml", line 1:
Error: Files ./longident.cmx
       and /home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs/ocamlcommon.cmxa
       both define a module named Longident
```

`-verbose`をつけた時の表示は以下のとおりです。

```
ocamlfind opt -package batteries,sexplib.syntax -linkpkg -syntax camlp4o -verbose ./longident.ml 
findlib: [WARNING] Interface longident.cmi occurs in several directories: ., /home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs
findlib: [WARNING] Interface topdirs.cmi occurs in several directories: /home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs, /home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml
Effective set of preprocessor predicates: preprocessor,syntax,camlp4o
Effective set of compiler predicates: pkg_unix,pkg_num.core,pkg_num,pkg_bigarray,pkg_str,pkg_bytes,pkg_batteries,pkg_camlp4,pkg_compiler-libs,pkg_compiler-libs.common,pkg_type_conv,pkg_sexplib,pkg_sexplib.syntax,syntax,autolink,native
+ ocamlopt.opt -verbose -I /home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/num -I /home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/bytes -I /home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/batteries -I /home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/camlp4 -I /home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs -I /home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/type_conv -I /home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/sexplib -pp "camlp4 '-I' '/home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/camlp4' '-I' '/home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs' '-I' '/home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs' '-I' '/home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/type_conv' '-I' '/home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml' '-I' '/home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml' '-I' '/home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/sexplib' '-I' '/home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/sexplib' '-parser' 'o' '-parser' 'op' '-printer' 'p' 'ocamlcommon.cma' 'pa_type_conv.cma' 'unix.cma' 'bigarray.cma' 'sexplib.cma' 'pa_sexp_conv.cma' " /home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/unix.cmxa /home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/nums.cmxa /home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/bigarray.cmxa /home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/str.cmxa /home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/batteries/batteries.cmxa /home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs/ocamlcommon.cmxa /home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/sexplib/sexplib.cmxa ./longident.ml
+ camlp4 '-I' '/home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/camlp4' '-I' '/home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs' '-I' '/home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs' '-I' '/home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/type_conv' '-I' '/home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml' '-I' '/home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml' '-I' '/home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/sexplib' '-I' '/home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/sexplib' '-parser' 'o' '-parser' 'op' '-printer' 'p' 'ocamlcommon.cma' 'pa_type_conv.cma' 'unix.cma' 'bigarray.cma' 'sexplib.cma' 'pa_sexp_conv.cma'  './longident.ml' > /tmp/ocamlpp0f6ab1
+ as -o './longident.o' '/tmp/camlasmc75b90.s'
File "./longident.ml", line 1:
Error: Files ./longident.cmx
       and /home/tokuda/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs/ocamlcommon.cmxa
       both define a module named Longident
ocamlopt.opt returned with exit code 2
```

Comment: compiler-libsがocamloptのオプションに渡されるのは-verboseをつけてみて理解しました。しかし何故つくのでしょうか。

Comment: `compiler-libs` は標準で入っているので OPAM のパッケージ名としては存在しません。だから依存していても OPAM のファイルには出てきません。batteries と sexplib の `META` ファイルには `compiler-libs` への依存情報がありますか？（私の手元の物にはありません…

Comment: `batteries`と`sexplib`のMETAファイルには見つけられませんでした。
`type_conv`のMETAファイルには`requires = "camlp4 compiler-libs.common"`と書かれているのでこれが原因なのでしょうか。。。

Comment: ああそれですね。質問にパッケージのバージョンを書いていただけませんか。手元のパッケージにそんな依存がないので

Comment: `type_conv.113.00.00.`でした。`113.01.00`で依存が消えるようで、パッケージを最新版にアップグレードしたら上のコンパイルコマンドで通るようになりました！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

解決したようで良かったです。いくつかポイントをあげておきます。

`ocamlfind` コマンドが何をやっているか判らないときは　`ocamlfind <command> -verbose ...` として実際にどんなコマンドが起動されるか確認する

OCamlFind パッケージと OPAM パッケージは違う。OCamlFind はライブラリの使用を助けるためのツールで、 OCamlFind パッケージはだいたいライブラリと一対一の関係にある。 OPAM はリリースされているソフトウェアパッケージと一対一の関係にありそのインストールを助ける。OPAM パッケージをインストールすると OCamlFind パッケージをインストールしないかもしれないし、するかもしれない。複数インストールすることもあり得る

OCamlFind はライブラリのリンク依存関係を `META` というファイルを使って把握する。OPAM パッケージの `opam` ファイルはソフトウェアパッケージとしてのインストール依存関係を表すもので、もちろん大体リンク依存関係と似てはいるが、同じではない。

`compiler-libs` ライブラリは OCaml コンパイラをインストールすると一緒にインストールされるので、対応する OPAM パッケージはない。 OCamlFind パッケージとしては存在する。OCaml コンパイラをインストールした時には OCamlFind は存在しないので、 `compiler-libs` という OCamlFind パッケージが存在するのはちょっと不思議だが、OCamlFind インストール時に勝手に作ってくれる。